# jqgrid custom function acces other field values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using Jqgrid in my project. For validation purpose I have defined custom function on each column. Like,

```
         { label: 'Name', name: 'Name', width: 300,
            editable:true, edittype:"custom", sortable:false,
            editoptions:{custom_element: getDatabaseColumnSelector,
                         custom_value:getSelectedDatabaseColumn},
            editrules:{required:true, custom:true, custom_func:somefunction}
          },
```

Here I use somefunction() for validation purpose, in this function I use other column values also for validation. Some thing like

```
          if employeecountry = "US" then name.length < 10
```

But in this function how can I get the employeecountry's value in Name column's custom function. I tried with

```
           "# + rowId + _columnname"
```

but this is not working in case with add form, since the rowId is not set at that time. How can I get other column values inside custom function defined in another column, which will work in edit form, inline edit and add form. Any help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [`custom_func`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules) is very restrictive, only providing `value` and `colname` parameter values. But you might be able to write some code to work around that.

You should be able to detect a form using code similar to:

```
jQuery('#FrmGrid_mygrid').length > 0
```

And then you should be able to use code like this access input elements on the form, although it will vary depending upon what type of input control is available:

```
jQuery('#mycolname', '#FrmGrid_mygrid').val()
```

Does that help?

It sounds like you already have code to get validation working in other scenarios such as inline edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    function my_custom_funct(v){ 
        thisId=$.jgrid.jqID(this.id); 
        var myval = $("#mycolname","#FrmGrid_"+thisId).val();
        alert (myval);
    }
```

$.jgrid.jqID(this.id);  get current Grid id.

$("#FrmGrid_"+thisId).val(); get current Fomr id